# KafkaStream - NullpointerException on transformation

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have bugs on my kafkaStream transformations :

```
"Exception in thread "transfo-app-id-ccb8146b-2c7b-4b09-881c-95d4f546dbe5-StreamThread-3" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: 
Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=TOPIC_NAME, partition=0, offset=0, 
stacktrace=java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "object.get()" because "object" is null"
```

However I do no suppress anything and tombstones should be drop.

```
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "true",
    "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode":"rewrite",
```

It is not always on the same transformation.
If this behavior sounds to nobody.

StackTrace : the bug is not always happened

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=1_0, processor=KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000039, topic=transfoX-app-id-KTABLE-FK-JOIN-SUBSCRIPTION-RESPONSE-0000000037-topic, partition=0, offset=192, stacktrace=java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Cannot invoke "x.getField()" because "x" is null
    at fr.adelaide.atlas.kafkastreams.process.RefRaisonSocialePMService.lambda$transfoX$3(RefRaisonSocialePMService.java:75)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:41)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorAdapter.process(ProcessorAdapter.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:181)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:883)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:181)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:273)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:172)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:41)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorAdapter.process(ProcessorAdapter.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:181)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:883)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:181)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:273)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:172)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableSource$KTableSourceProcessor.process(KTableSource.java:125)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorAdapter.process(ProcessorAdapter.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:181)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:883)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:181)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:273)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:172)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.foreignkeyjoin.SubscriptionResolverJoinProcessorSupplier$1.process(SubscriptionResolverJoinProcessorSupplier.java:108)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.foreignkeyjoin.SubscriptionResolverJoinProcessorSupplier$1.process(SubscriptionResolverJoinProcessorSupplier.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorAdapter.process(ProcessorAdapter.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:181)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:883)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:181)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:273)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$1(StreamTask.java:701)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:883)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:701)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:1105)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:658)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:564)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:523)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:718)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:1105)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:658)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:564)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:523)
```

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace and streams code

Comment: ok if I have the bug again i'll do it

Comment: So, it no longer happens? If not [edit] your question now to include the code, please